# Safari does not recognize border-radius for a link styled as a button

Tags: html, css, safari

I have the following html:

```css
a {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: initial;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="github">
  <a href="https://github.com/theghall">Github repos</a>
</div>
```

This works in Chrome.  In Safari 11.1.2 it does display as a button, but border-radius and box-shadow have no effect.

Comment: There is no border radius in Chrome or Safari for me.

Comment: You could replicate the button style easily if you really wanted to http://jsfiddle.net/zw9ke4v1/4/

Comment: Weird.  Try this link: https://theghall.github.io/portfolio/

Comment: Your site looks exactly the same. No border-radius in Chrome. No border-radius or  box-shadow in Safari.

Comment: I am using normalize, perhaps that has an effect?  Regardless ditching appearance: button and using a class seems the better route.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove these lines:

```
-webkit-appearance: button;
   -moz-appearance: button;
        appearance: button;
```

And recreate the button style using CSS. You'll mainly need a border, a box-shadow and a gradient background.

The appearance is conflicting with the button appearance. I had the same issue while trying to style a dropdown for iOS. It was impossible, until I recreated it using CSS.